# GridView and HyperLink Column passing an Encrypt QueryString Value to the specified page

Tags: gridview, hyperlink

I have a grid which loads some data from DB at the page load. the id column is a hyperlink column, on clicking the column it should navigate to the next page with the id which should be in an encrypted format.

Answer (score 1):

i think you should create new hyperlink column class derived from original one and override formatting inside with encryption capability.

exmaple :

```
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls

Public Class MyHyperlinkColumn
    Inherits HyperLinkColumn
    Protected Overrides Function FormatDataNavigateUrlValue(ByVal dataUrlValue As Object) As String
        Dim strdata As String
        Dim encr As New AnyWebEncrytor()
        strdata = String.Format(Me.DataNavigateUrlField, encr.Encrypt(CStr(dataUrlValue)))
        Return strdata 'MyBase.FormatDataNavigateUrlValue(dataUrlValue)
    End Function
End Class
```